# 8 $\alpha$ and 8 $\beta$

Tags: combinatorics

We have 8 $\alpha$ and 8 $\beta$. How many sequences do we have if between 2 $\alpha$ we have at least one $\beta$. I know that it will be sum, but probably I have to use floor and celling, but don't know when which one in formula. I think I should use this formula: $2\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1}{m-1\choose k-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9.

The key is abababababababa which uses 7 of the b's. The last b can go in front of the string or behind the string, or next to any other b.